# Uninitialized string offset error

Tags: php, string, uninitialized-constant

Why I am getting uninitialized string error, I can't figure out?

Here is my function:

```
function show_site_name($url,$lenght)
{
    $name='';
    $i=0;
    $slash=0;
    while($slash<3 && $i<=$lenght)
    {
        if($url[$i]=='/') $slash++;
        if($url[$i]!='/' && $slash==2) $name.=$url[$i];
        $i++;
    }
    return($name);
}
```

EDITED:
I am getting "Uninitialized string offset" error at this two lines here:

```
    if($url[$i]=='/') $slash++;
    if($url[$i]!='/' && $slash==2) $name.=$url[$i];
```

Comment: FWIW http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php As for your question. Show how you call that function.

Comment: `<=` should just be `<`. You're acceessing outside the string when you reach the last iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is rather silly. PHP offers nice native functions for [parsing a url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). Also, I assume "lenght" is the length of the first argument? Which can of course be derived with `strlen`.

```
show_site_name('http://www.example.com', strlen('http://www.example.com'));
```

Will result in `Uninitialized string offset: 22`.

```
show_site_name('http://www.example.com', strlen('http://www.example.com')-1);
```

The above is probably what you want. Option base zero, not one.

```
if($url[$i]=='/') $slash++;
```

The line above is where you exceed the string offset. Bad logic. You can fix the code and avoid it or handle it with `isset`. Trust your error log.

**UPDATE:**

You can avoid it by passing sane arguments like I showed. Or change it to:

```
if (isset($url[$i])) {
    if($url[$i]=='/') $slash++;
} else {
    return $name;
}
```

But again, that is just silly.

If you insist on doing this, let's call it for learning purposes. Why not do:

```
function show_site_name($url)
{
    $lenght = strlen($url) -1;
    ...
```

Passing a second argument that can simply be derived from the first argument is not a good approach.

Comment: isset on which variable ? how I can fix it ?

Comment: Thanks for the update you're magician! The problem is solved, cheers!

Comment: I cant give you up vote, because I got message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." - but thank you so much anyway !

Comment: You should **accept** the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: have done, thanks! maybe better to be there "thumb up" (like on facebook, hehehe!)